# Why my implicit ContextMenu Style doesn't override the TextBox context menu style?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this implicit style for the `ContextMenu` that I took from [this site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744758(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
<Application.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidBorderBrush" Color="#888" />

        <Style TargetType="ContextMenu">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContextMenu">
                        <Border 
          Name="Border"
          Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
          BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="1" >
                            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                      KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Padding" Value="0,3,0,3"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Then I try to use it here so it gest applied both for the default `ContextMenu` of the `TextBox` and the `ContextMenu` I added for my `Button`.

```
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Height="30" Width="200">Test</TextBox>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Width="200" Height="30" Content="Test2">
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem>Test</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>Test2</MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

The style gets applied on the `Button`, but not on the `TextBox`.

I feel this should be rather straightforward and simple, why isn't my implicit style getting applied to the default `ContextMenu` of the `TextBox`, what am I doing wrong?

**==Update==**

I don't know the answer for sure at the moment, but I think the issue here is some flaw in the Design of the `TextBox` with the `ContextMenu`, I wish someone more knowledgeable could confirm.
Using Snoop I could see that the `ContextMenu` wasn't the object you would expect, but an `EditorContextMenu` object, that is internal, so you can't style it. Why do they use that? I don't know.

As a work around, I create a default context menu and use it. If you add a context menu to the `TextBox`, it correctly takes the implicit styling.
Since you know the items that the default `ContextMenu` has, and the items in turn basically use the ApplicationCommands, it is very simple:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="DefaultContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" />
        <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" />
        <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" />        
    </ContextMenu>
```

Then in your TextBoxStyle do:

```
<Style x:Key="MyTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource DefaultContextMenu}" />
```

With this your `TextBox`'s Default `ContextMenu` will take the implicit style.

Comment: Where's your resource dictionary live? Somewhere in there is a line like `<Style TargetType="ContextMenu" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContextMenu}}" />` where you'll just change the basedon value to reference your new style as the global default.

Comment: @ChrisW. - I am sorry, I don't understand. As you can see in my code I have an implicit style for `ContextMenu` defined inside the Application Resources: `<Style TargetType="ContextMenu">`. I tried adding it to different levels but it doesn't work in any of them.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I have the same issue :(

Comment: @mgarant - Well no-one ever answered why this is happening, and from using snoop it seems some flaw in the design, but I found a work around, I posted as an update.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in `TextBox` implementation for me and the peculiarity is that `ContextMenu` does not belong to the VisualTree.

I will try to explain it.

- The default `ContextMenu` will be created and shown by the `TextBox`
  implementation, namely in the method
  `OnContextMenuOpening(ContextMenuEventArgs e)`. To see it you can
  override this method in custom `TextBox` and omit the `base.` call.
- Compared to `ContextMenu`, which is set explicitly, the default `ContextMenu` is
  handled different (handled not via `ContextMenuService`).
- The default `ContextMenu` will be created by the `TextBox` only if the
  `TextBox.ContextMenu` property was not set explicitly(XAML or code behind).
- `ContextMenu` is not in VisualTree and the only connection to the
  VisualTree is the property `PlacementTarget` (if you e.g. do create
  and open a `ContextMenu` in code behind and do not set a
  `PlacementTarget` the implicit style will not be applied).
- **In `TextBox` implementation the `ContextMenu.PlacementTarget` being set, BUT the value comes from some internal cache/dictionary**. I could not
  debug it and say for sure, but I suppose the cached value is wrong
  here. 
   You can do small test to see the cached value is correct. Override the `OnContextMenuOpening(ContextMenuEventArgs e)` for the custom
  `TextBox` and before you call the base function do modify the
  `TextBox` (e.g. set each time another `Margin`). The default `ContextMenu` will not be even opened! If you in place of `base` call do instantiate and show
  the `ContextMenu` by yourself, then `Margin` modification
  will not disturb and opened `ContextMenu` will have implicit style you set in the resources.

**Snippet to test**:

```
public class MyStyledTextBox: TextBox
{
    protected override void OnContextMenuOpening(ContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        //this.Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0);

        var uiScope = e.Source as TextBox;

        var ctxm = new ContextMenu();

        MenuItem menuItem;
        menuItem = new MenuItem();
        menuItem.Header = "CutCustom";
        menuItem.CommandTarget = this;
        menuItem.Command = ApplicationCommands.Cut;
        ctxm.Items.Add(menuItem);

        ctxm.PlacementTarget = uiScope;

        ctxm.IsOpen = true;

        //base.OnContextMenuOpening(e);
    }
}

<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ContextMenu" >
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContextMenu">
                        <Border  Name="Border_custom" Background="Chocolate" BorderBrush="Coral" BorderThickness="1" >
                            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border_custom" Property="Padding" Value="0,3,0,3"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Border_custom" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <local:MyStyledTextBox Height="30" Width="200" Text="Test">
        <!--<TextBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Test"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Test2"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </TextBox.ContextMenu>-->
    </local:MyStyledTextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

**I'm saying about bug, because of `ScrollBar` implementation of default `ContextMenu` does apply an implicit style correctly**.

The bad news is, that in current implementation of `TextBox` you can't reach the internally created default `ContextMenu` and the implicit style being not applied.